pydantic field_validator invoking problem
someone before asked this question but the answers didnt help in my case, im trying to use an app called powershell-empire starkiller on kali linux, running it from terminal looks like: sudo powershell-empire server but then i get the error: ImportError: cannot import 'field_validator' from 'pydantic'(/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydantic/init.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so). Did you mean: 'root_validator'?
so i made a virtual environment, installed pydantic there and installed powershell-empire there, i tried to run this again and got the same error so i made a simple python file, imported field_validator from pydantic tried to run the program and it DIDNT give any error so looks like the problme isnt from pydantic but the error message is a bit confusing idk, is the problem from cpython? can someone please help
pydantic version: 2.9.2
python3.12.6

Didn't you replace 'root_validator'?

@toyotaSupra how? the code needs field_validator to run

I am not familiar with powershell-empire server and Kali.  pip install --upgrade pydantic

Apologies, posting as I don't have enough reputation to reply in thread.
I am not familiar with powershell-empire but I would recommend you post a bug to their bug tracker. That will be your best bet for catching the right people's attention. Best of luck :)

https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/powershell-empire
https://bugs.kali.org/view_all_bug_page.php

